# msbuild Directory.build.props cascade per project?

Tags: msbuild

Executive Summary: I want to set properties in property groups based on conditions that are present only late in the build pipeline and am looking for a way to solve this earlier.

I have a fairly simple `Directory.build.props` file

```xml
<Project>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <MyMode>Default</MyMode>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <!-- This one overrides the default group above -->
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">
    <MyMode>Changed to Debug</MyMode>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <!-- This one is not applied -->
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFrameworkVersion)' == 'v4.7.2' ">
    <MyMode>Framework</MyMode>
  </PropertyGroup>


  <Target Name="Stats" AfterTargets="Build">
    <Message Importance="High" Text="::::: Mode set to $(MyMode)" />
    <Message Importance="High" Text="::::: Target Framework set to $(TargetFrameworkVersion)" />
  </Target>

</Project>
```

And a simple project structure

```
E:.
│   Directory.build.props
│   MSBuild_Test.sln
│
├───ConsoleAppNet
│       App.config
│       ConsoleAppNet.csproj
│       Program.cs
│
└───MSBuild_Test
        Class1.cs
        LibStandard.csproj
```

`LibStandard` is a .net standard library, `ConsoleAppNet` is a .net framework project which also has a build dependency to `LibStandard`

When I execute the msbuild script above I get this output

```
  LibStandard -> E:\temp\MSBuild_Test\MSBuild_Test\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\LibStandard.dll
  ::::: Mode set to Changed to Debug
  ::::: Target Framework set to v2.0
  ConsoleAppNet -> E:\temp\MSBuild_Test\ConsoleAppNet\bin\Debug\ConsoleAppNet.exe
  ::::: Mode set to Changed to Debug
  ::::: Target Framework set to v4.7.2
```

As you can see, the console output should have triggered the property group with the condition resulting in `MyMode` being `Framework`, but it did not work out. This one was never matched:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFrameworkVersion)' == 'v4.7.2' ">
    <MyMode>Framework</MyMode>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Is there a good way to apply `PropertyGroups` during load based on the condition above?

I am aware that I can place PropertyGroup overrides in a Target, e.g.:

```
  <Target Name="TooLate" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild" Condition=" '$(TargetFrameworkVersion' == 'v4.7.2' ">
    <PropertyGroup >
      <MyMode>Framework</MyMode>
    </PropertyGroup>
  </Target>
```

and it also gets executed correctly but at this point in time I cannot set important other variables.

My intention is to *redirect output directories* based on different conditions. When I set `$(OutputPath)` in a target, it is already too late. The project ignores this output for the entire build of this project:

```
  <Target Name="TooLate" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild" Condition=" '$(TargetFrameworkVersion)' == 'v4.7.2' ">
    <PropertyGroup >
      <OutputPath>New_Output_Directory</OutputPath>
    </PropertyGroup>
  </Target>
```

I can even echo the `OutputPath` variable and it points to the correct value but the build uses the old value and not redirecting the output.

Answer (score 5):

High five me, I found the solution for all the coming up Samuels asking about the same issue.

## Quick answer

At the time of import of the `Directory.build.props` no other properties (e.g TargetFramework) are already imported and will *default* to **empty**. This is why the checks on them fail. Use `Directory.build.targets` instead!

- `Directory.build.props` imported very *early*, allowing you to set properties at the beginning
- `Directory.build.targets` imported very *late*, allowing you to customize the build chain

## Resources

Here are some very useful pages regarding msbuild

- [Explanation of available targets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-targets?view=vs-2019)
- [How to customize your build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019)

## Explanation

Here is a quote from the [paragraph on the customization page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019#import-order) (so long the current documents are alive ...)

> **Import order**
>
> **Directory.Build.props** is imported very early in
>   Microsoft.Common.props, and properties defined later are unavailable
>   to it. So, avoid referring to properties that are not yet defined (and
>   will evaluate to empty).
>
> **Directory.Build.targets** is imported from Microsoft.Common.targets
>   after importing .targets files from NuGet packages. So, it can
>   override properties and targets defined in most of the build logic,
>   but sometimes you may need to customize the project file after the
>   final import.

By reading this the implication is somewhat fuzzy about the targets but `Directory.Build.targets` is the best place to override properties and use conditional checks.